# Why the equation of an arbitrary straight line in complex plane is $zz_o + \bar z \bar z_0 = D$

Tags: complex-numbers

Why the equation of an arbitrary straight line in complex plane is $zz_o + \bar z \bar z_0 = D$ where D $\in R$

I understand that a vertical straight line can be defined by the equation $z+\bar z= D$ because suppose $z =x+yi$ then $\bar z = x-yi$   Thus, $z+\bar z = x+yi+x-yi=2x$ which is an arbitrary vertical straight line in w-plane.

But why $zz_o + \bar z \bar z_0 = D$ is an arbitrary straight line in complex plane?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Straight Line Equation in Complex Plane](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/934323/straight-line-equation-in-complex-plane)

Answer (score 4):

You know that a vertical straight line can be defined as $z+\bar z= D$, so if you rotate it's points with angle $\theta$ you get $(e^{i\theta}z)+ \overline{(e^{i\theta}z)}= D$ or $e^{i\theta}z + e^{-i\theta}\overline{z}= D$ and with arbitrary real $r\neq0$,
$$re^{i\theta}z + re^{-i\theta}\overline{z}= rD$$
gives us
$$zz_0 +\bar{z}\bar{z_0}= D_0$$
where $z_0=re^{i\theta}$ and $D_0=rD$.

Comment: Why we can rotate its points by multiply $e^{i \theta}$

Comment: To find arbitrary sloped line!

Answer (score 2):

**HINT:**

$$z+\bar z=2\text{Re}(z)\implies zz_0+\bar z\bar z_0=2\text{Re}(zz_0)$$

Comment: But we still only get an arbitrary vertical straight line not a straight line right?

Comment: We get any line we want.  Note $\text{Re}(zz_0)=xx_0-yy_0$

Comment: I still don't get it. Once we get a real part a complex number. The equation becomes w=1,2,3,4 or any real numbers , but there are all vertical lines

Comment: $xx_0-yy_0=D\implies y=\frac{x_0}{y_0}x-\frac{D}{y_0}$ for $y_0\ne 0$.  That is the equation of a straight line.

Comment: is x the coordinate in real part and y the coordinate in imaginary part?

Comment: Yes, that is correct.

Comment: Would the downvoter care to comment?

Answer (score 1):

Hint: given any two points $z_1, z_2 \in \mathbb{C}\,$, then $z$ is collinear with $z_1, z_2$ iff there exists $\lambda \in \mathbb{R}$ such that $z-z_1 = \lambda(z-z_2)$. Eliminate $\lambda$ between the following, then define $z_0, D$ appropriately:

$$
\begin{cases}
\begin{align}
z-z_1 &= \lambda(z-z_2) \\
\bar z- \bar z_1 &= \lambda(\bar z- \bar z_2)
\end{align}
\end{cases}
$$

Answer (score 0):

Hack the equation.

Substitute:

$$
\begin{cases}
z = x + iy   \\
z_0 = x_0 + iy_0 
\end{cases}
$$

Do some algebraic manipulations and you'll obtain the equation of a line.

Maybe what confuses you is that neither $z_0$ nor $D$ have a clear geometric interpretation in terms of intercepts, distance to the origin, etc...

Hope this helps!

Comment: I do the manipulation and I get $2xx_0-2yy_0 =R$  and is it a straight line about x and y? and is x the coordinate in real part and y the coordinate in imaginary part?

Comment: That's the equation of a line in $\mathbb{R}^2$ which is isomorphic with $\mathbb{C}$ and $z = x + iy$