# how do I prove the general form of a line in $\Bbb{C}$

Tags: complex-analysis

Show the general form of a line in $\Bbb{C}$ is of the form

$$a\overline{z}+ \overline{a}z+C = 0$$

where $0 \neq a \in \Bbb{C}$ and $C \in \Bbb{R}$.

Do we start with setting $z=x+iy$, $a=u+iv$? A bit confused on this one.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2344227/equation-of-a-line-in-complex-plane

Comment: What's the definition of a "line"?

Comment: @fleablood y = mx+b?

Comment: Can I assume there's a line $ax+by+c=0$ in the reals and build off that? @fleablood

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could definitely start that way.

Using your notation described above, note that $z + \bar z = 2x$ and $\bar z-z = -2iy$. Then

\begin{align*}
&a\bar z + \bar az + C = 0\\
\iff & u\bar z+ iv\bar z + uz -ivz+C=0\\
\iff & u(z+\bar z) +iv(\bar z-z) + C=0\\
\iff & 2ux -iv(2iy) + C=0\\
\iff & ux + vy = D,
\end{align*}
where the last equation is a line in $\mathbb R^2$ written in standard form.

Comment: I got that too, but I ended up using the fact that there's a line in reals of form $ax+by+c=0$ where $x+iy=z$ then using the real and imaginary parts I substituted.